# how to set a listbox background color

Tags: c, winapi, listbox

I don't know how set a `ListBox` background color, not just one item.

`g_hChatEdit(listbox)`

Code:

```
case WM_MEASUREITEM:
    if ((UINT)wParam == IDE_CHATEDIT) {
        LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpmis = (LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
        lpmis->itemHeight = 22;
        HBRUSH hbr = CreateSolidBrush(bkgrgb);
        SetWindowLong(g_hChatEdit, GCL_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG)hbr);
        //BeginPaint(g_hChatEdit, &ps);
        hdc=GetDC(g_hChatEdit);
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(g_hChatEdit, &rc);
        FillRect(hdc, &rc, hbr);
        InvalidateRect(g_hChatEdit, 0, true);
        UpdateWindow(g_hChatEdit);
        return true;
    }
    break;
```

the listbox background color still is white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this one works. Note that `hbrBkgnd` should not be a temporary variable.

```
HBRUSH hbrBkgnd = NULL;

       case WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX: //or WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC
       if ((UINT)lParam == g_hChatEdit) 
       {
            HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;
            SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(255,255,255));
            SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0,128,0));
            if (hbrBkgnd == NULL)
                hbrBkgnd = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(200,200,255));
            return (INT_PTR)hbrBkgnd;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

according to this board

[How to change background color of a list box? @ codeguru](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?341112-How-to-change-background-color-of-a-list-box)

you would need the parent window to intercept the `WM_CTLCOLOR` or one of [these variant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages to supply the your desired color to the control.